# WPF toolkit ColorPicker in DataGrid lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I have a WPF DataGrid with a ColorPicker column. All works fine, but when the user try to click on the advanced button (see picture), the ColorPicker close.

[image]

When the user click again in the column, the ColorPicker opens and suddenly the "Advanced" button works. But when he click on a other column, it opens, he want click the advanced button, the ColorPicker close.

Here is the code of the DataTemplate in XAML file

```
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <xceed:ColorPicker SelectedColor="{Binding Color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource StringToWindowsMediaColorConverter}}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Any suggestions, how can I fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Really nobody has any suggestions?

Comment: I’ve never used the WPF Toolking (or Xceed Software) due to uncertainty with the licensing of their free controls, but I know that the `ColorComboBox` posted at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229442/WPF-Color-Picker-VS2010-Style works great—I’ve successfully used it myself inside a `DataGrid`.

Comment: Any chance you've come up with a solution and remember it?  Been a while since this post has had any attention.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I made the following workaround.

I bind the `IsOpen` Property of the `ColorPicker` to a new Property. Then I add a new column to the grid. In this column, I put a new button which pushes the `IsOpen` Property. I set the column with the `ColorPicker` on `IsEnabled = false`. So the only way to open the picker is the button-column. When the `ColorPicker` is openened by the button, it works normally and stays open until a color is clicked. Switching between the standard and advanced is no problem.

To create a new column to open the colorpicker is not nice, but I found no other solution.